# Anagram Between 2 Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, anagram

So I make 2 arrays from user input, and I want to check if that array **b** is an anagram to array **a**, something like that, but I don't know how hope u guys can help me with it

```
a = arr.array('i', [])
b = arr.array('B', [])

k = int(input("Masukkan Banyaknya Elemen A:"))
for i in range(0, k):
    num = int(input("Masukkan Elemen A ke-%d :" % (i + 1)))
    a.append(num)
    
print("All array A elements are:", end="")
for i in a:
    print(i, end=" ")
    
l = int(input("\n"+"Masukkan Banyaknya Elemen B:"))
for B in range(0, l):
    num = int(input("Masukkan Elemen B ke-%d :" % (B + 1)))
    b.append(num)
    
print("All array B elements are:", end="")
for B in b:
    print(B, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, ideally, we can use a dictionary to keep counter of all the letters and check later.

Code:-

```
def counter(s):
    string_list = []
    for ch in s.lower():
        string_list.append(ch)

    string_dict = {}
    for c in string_list:
        if c not in string_dict:
            string_dict[c] = 1
        else:
            string_dict[c] = string_dict[c] + 1

    return string_dict


s1 = "anagram"
s2 = "nagaram"

a = counter(s1)
b = counter(s2)

if a == b:
    print("Anagram")
else:
    print("Not Anagram")
```

Using some sort of sorting function(like sorted) is more compute expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
if sorted(A) == sorted(B):
    print('A and B are anagrams.')
```